# Can 'this', as in 'this day' or 'on this day' be used for future reference?

Tags: time, semantics, demonstratives, deixis

I have recently stumbled upon this sentence:

> ***5th June*** is perfect. Do you think you can come **this day**?

The time frame of the utterance was more than two weeks before the date mentioned. And I am quite confident that the author was a non-native speaker of English.

Now, I am aware that *this* can convey the idea of spatial and temporal closeness, yet for some reason, I cannot avoid the impression that *that* would be more appropriate in this sentence.

Am I on to something, or am I completely mistaken? Perhaps I have fallen victim to the sticky tentacles of my overthinking mind.

Many thanks for any enlightenment!

Comment: I am not sure if there is a rule for it, but I would definitely say "that". I would, however, also use a preposition with it: "Do you think you can come on that day?"

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I would also use "on", I forgot to mention that. On the other hand, while I cannot imagine leaving out "on" before "this day", "that day" does not sound completely unacceptable to me without it. Intriguing. Anyway, thank you once more!

Comment: @PavelJetušek I think you're right, I don't think you need to use "on" with "that day."

Comment: *This* sounds okay to me. It's a deictic *this*. You're both looking at your calendars—tapping, penciling, poking, whatever—on a square right now (even though the square represents something in the future).

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thank you! You're right. The more I think of it, the more it sounds natural to me as well—but that's the problem with introspection, I'm afraid.